# An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500

Tags: ajax, panels, debugging

Everytime I try to edit content on one of my panels I get the following error message.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /panels/ajax/editor/edit-pane/panel_context%3Apage-   sign_up_page%3A%3Apage_sign_up_page_panel_context%3A%3A%3A%3A/417
StatusText: Internal Server Error
ResponseText:
```

I am using Panels 7.x-3.5.  Anyone have any idea how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Check your Drupal logs, do you see anything suspicious there when you perform the same action?

Comment: HTTP 500 really means "check your logs". If you see nothing in Drupal watchdog, then you should check your webserver's (apache?) logs. without log message your question is unanswerable

Answer (score 1):

You guys were right and it was a problem with CKEditor and Media not working well together.  I fixed it using a patch found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2455391